# How can i find whether the CouchDB is up and running?

Tags: ios, couchdb

As far as I know, couch db instance can't be run in background, that is, if the user switches the app to background from foreground, the database is effectively not reachable. and it would take a few moments to restart after a user switches the app to foreground, is there a way to find whether the DB is up and running,once the app resumes to foreground?

Waiting for your reply,

Krishna.

Comment: What about querying the DB and see if it's responding?

Comment: thanks simon, this will do my work, but wanted to know if any API will serve my purpose.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of constantly polling, using the [changes API](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/HTTP%5Fdatabase%5FAPI#Changes), you can have a *continuous* feed with a *heartbeat*.

The default heartbeat is 1 minute but you can make it shorter if you like.

Comment: thank you very much @simon, As i found Polling the CouchDB server is not a good thing to do. Setting up new HTTP connections just to tell the client that nothing's happened puts unnecessary strain on CouchDB.
   A continuous feed stays open and connected to the database until explicitly closed and changes are sent to the client as they happen, 
   The continuous feed's response will be either empty or a JSON object representing a single change, as found in the normal feed's results.It would be more helpful if someone provide the code snippet(objc) to do the above.

Answer (score 0):

What are you running couchdb on?  Linux? Windows?

I would recommend IrisCouch.com, they let you use a couchdb instance in the cloud free as long as you just use it for development.  And then you can use cURL from the terminal to check if couchdb is running, like so...

```
costa: curl http://wamoyo.iriscouch.com/bank
{"db_name":"bank","doc_count":6,"doc_del_count":0,"update_seq":6,"purge_seq":0,"compact_running":false,"disk_size":32859,"instance_start_time":"1330714407415725","disk_format_version":5,"committed_update_seq":6}
```

Note: costa is just my username in my terminal, wamoyo is my couch on iriscouch your's will be different, and bank is the name of one of my databses, your's will be different.

Then you should go over to the futon interface: mine would be at: http://wamoyo.iriscouch.com/_utils

Hope this is helpful!

Comment: i am using iOS and objective c for development, i want things to happen programatically. anyways thank you costa, for the kind information. right now i am using ASIHttpRequest to contineously ping the DB and see if its alive. Is there any better solution other than this?

Comment: Hmmm...I'm not very familiar with iOS, but I do have some minimal experience with couch on android. If you need to do a scheduled sync, that's a good idea, you can also check before any operation that needs access to the cloud.  I'm sorry I won't be helpful technically I don't have enough experience with iOS.